# requirejs: cache with local storage?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, local-storage

Do you know if there's a framework which adds local storage caching of scripts loaded by requirejs? I've been trying to make it work myself, but the fallback path feature is inherently convoluted to implement.

This is what I've got, and it isn't working for those files which use relative module references.

```
// Inspired by https://github.com/andrewwakeling/requirejs-basketjs/blob/master/basket-loader.js
(function (rjs) {
  rjs.load = function (context, moduleName, url) {
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    var hash = computeHash(moduleName);
    var key = 's' + hash;
    console.log(url);
    if (storage && storage[key] !== undefined) {
      complete(context, moduleName, storage[key]);
    }

    fetch(context, moduleName, url);
  }

  function complete(context, moduleName, data) {
    var hash = computeHash(moduleName);
    var node = document.getElementById('rjs-mod-' + hash);

    if (!node) {
      node = document.createElement('script');
      node.id = 'rjs-mod-' + hash;
      node.type = 'text/javascript';
      node.charset = 'utf-8';
      node.defer = true;
      node.text = data;
      document.head.appendChild(node);
    }

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      context.completeLoad(moduleName);
    }, 0);
  }

  function fetch(context, moduleName, url) {
    var hash = computeHash(moduleName);
    var tmp = complete;

    // alas, hackish...
    $.get(url).done(function (data) {
      window.localStorage['s' + hash] = data;
      tmp(context, moduleName, data);
    }).fail(function (err) {
      // fallback ...
      context.onError(err);
    });
  }

  function computeHash(moduleName) {
    var pos = moduleName.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (pos !== -1)
      moduleName = moduleName.substr(pos, 1);

    return moduleName.hashCode();
  }

} (requirejs));
```

So my question *isn't* about someone correcting my code, but rather if you guys know of a framework which encapsulates requirejs in local storage functionality!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked James Burke on Twitter, and this is his reply:

[@parmaeldo](https://twitter.com/parmaeldo) not off the top of my head, but have heard of it. Override requirejs.load to do it. Or, if an option for the site, use appcache

— James Burke (@jrburke) [31 januari 2015](https://twitter.com/jrburke/status/561560651072430080)